# Android Layout rendering issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[image]My Layout design look like below.I am using android studio.
But it shows "The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate: 
- Path.isConvex is not supported. (Ignore for this session)" error.
Can Anybody help me ???`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_back" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_back"
        android:text="Product Title"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_cart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_shop_icon" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/img_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_cart" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/app_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Product Short Name"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_price"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/black_rounded_corner"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="$99"
                android:textColor="@color/edtitext_back"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_productimage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_price"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quantity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Quantity"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/quantity_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/quantity"
                    android:background="@drawable/dropdown"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:popupBackground="@color/sky"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView android:id="@+id/availability"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:text="Availability"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/availability"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_size"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SIZE"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="24sp"

                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_size"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/img_size1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="XS"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/img_size2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="S"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/img_size3"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="M"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/img_size4"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="L"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_whislist"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#cccccc"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ADD TO WHISLIST"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_adtocart"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ADD TO CART"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

`

Comment: can you please show your layout image

Comment: Hello jain i attach my main layout design

Comment: @MusafirAli check your black_rounded_corner.xml I have answered below about the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The rendering issue, I saw that you are using

```
android:background="@drawable/black_rounded_corner"
```

just go into this xml and if you are using

```
<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
 android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
 android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
```

something like this just change it into

```
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
```